# Custom control with invalid property generates no error

Tags: asp.net, controls, properties

for examle

```
<app:CustomDropDown ID="test" runat="server" InvalidProperty="SOMETHING" />
```

This does not generate an error. Sometimes i spend hours trying to figure out why my custom controls are displaying no data. Most of the time it turns out they are using and old non existing property and yet no error is generated on execution.

What could cause this?

Comment: Maybe clean your solution and rebuild?  Your post doesn't have enough information to suggest any more than that.

Comment: Please show some code. Are you saying that your server side code is using non-existing properties, but the compiler doesn't pick up on this? Or are your .aspx pages using these properties?

Comment: i just get no errors neither on build nor when i run the page containing the custom control. i just tested this on a normal server control (checkbox) and i also dont get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting an error because, technically, there's nothing wrong with the markup. ASP.NET will pass any un-recognized attributes through to the page.

This can be useful if you want to use some non-standard attributes to store extra data for some reason and then access it later through the DOM.

Comment: well isn't there any way to force the app to throw an error if it finds an non existing property in the markup?